# A more elegant proof of $[(a,b),c]=([a,c],[b,c])$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So assuming the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and using the definitions $(a,b)=\prod_i^{\infty}p_i^{\min\left\{a_i,b_i\right\}}$ and $[a,b]=\prod_i^{\infty}p_i^{\max\left\{a_i,b_i\right\}}$ with $a_i,b_i=0$ for nearly all $i$ we can write it like this: $[(a,b),c]=\prod_i^{\infty}p_i^{\max\left\{\min\left\{a_i,b_i\right\},c_i\right\}}$ and $([a,c],[b,c])=\prod_i^{\infty}p_i^{\min\left\{\max\left\{a_i,c_i\right\},\max\left\{b_i,c_i\right\}\right\}}$. So proving the statement amounts to proving $\max\left\{\min\left\{a_i,b_i\right\},c_i\right\}=\min\left\{\max\left\{a_i,c_i\right\},\max\left\{b_i,c_i\right\}\right\}$, right? I could prove the general statement by evaluating every possible case, but that seems a bit hamhanded to me. Any better ideas?

Comment: Note that the equation is symmetric in terms of $a$ and $b$. Hence you can assume $a_i\leq b_i$. Then you just need to consider fewer cases for $c_i$.

Comment: A good hint. Otherwise, is the basic approach okay?